# Chatbot Sqlite3 error on Digital Ocean server

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, digital-ocean

I have been building a Chatbot on which running perfectly on my local PC and also on Amazon web serve, but I want to implemented these chatbot on Digital ocean server since my website is running on Digital ocean's server. I am getting these Sqlite error

```
[pythondemo@panel Chatbot]$ python3.6 chatbot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatbot.py", line 8, in <module>
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
  File "/home/pythondemo/.local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/home/pythondemo/.local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 50, in <module>
    version_info = tuple([int(x) for x in version.split(".")])
NameError: name 'version' is not defined
```

These is the code which i am trying to run:

```
import os
import sys
import datetime
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
import random
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite



bot = ChatBot('Bot')
bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
for files in os.listdir('C:/Users/OMI/Desktop/chatterbot-corpus-master/chatterbot_corpus/data/english/'):
    data = open('C:/Users/OMI/Desktop/chatterbot-corpus-master/chatterbot_corpus/data/english/' + files, 'r').readlines()
    bot.train(data)

t=datetime.datetime.now().hour

start_greeting = ('hello', 'hi', 'welcome', 'hey')
end_greeting = ('bye', 'cya', 'goodbye')

random_start_greeting = random.choice(start_greeting)
random_end_greeting = random.choice(end_greeting)

message = ' '.join(word for word in sys.argv)
message = message.replace("chatbot.py ","")

if message.strip() in start_greeting:
    reply = random_start_greeting
    print(reply.strip())
    if (t <= 12 and t >= 5):
        print("Welcome! Good Morning.")
    elif (t < 17 and t > 12):
        print("Welcome! Good Afternoon.")
    elif (t < 20 and t >= 17):
        print("Welcome! Good Evening.")
    elif (t < 23 and t >= 20):
        print("Welcome! Hope you had a great day.")

elif message.strip() in end_greeting:
    reply = random_end_greeting
    print(reply)

else:
   reply = bot.get_response(message)
    print("hello")
```